# Join command not working

Tags: bash, join

I'm having problems with this:

```
FILE1:        FILE2
1000          1000
1001          1003
1002          1007
1003          1009
1004          1010
1005
1006
1007
1008
1009
1010
```

And I'd like to have this output:

```
OUTPUT:
1000          1000
1001         
1002 
1003          1003
1004         
1005
1006
1007          1007
1008
1009          1009
1010          1010
```

I've thougth to use join, but it does nothing.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Left join from file1 (`-a 1`) and output the first field from each file (`-o 1.1,2.1`):

```
$ join -a 1 -o 1.1,2.1  file1 file2
1000 1000
1001 
1002 
1003 1003
1004 
1005 
1006 
1007 1007
1008 
1009 1009
1010 1010
```

Answer (score 1):

check this, if it does what you want:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}$0=$0 (a[$0]?" "$0:"")' f2 f1 
1000 1000
1001
1002
1003 1003
1004
1005
1006
1007 1007
1008
1009 1009
1010 1010
```